# Select multiple e-mails in Gmail web with only one hand?

Tags: gmail

In the Gmail web version, I select multiple e-mails by clicking the first e-mail and then the last e-mail while pressing a Shift key which needs two hands.

Can I do this with only one hand?

Comment: @BlindSpots Yes, it is on Windows 10/11. The web browser is Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Windows Sticky Keys

You should leverage Windows Sticky Keys.

This will allow you to temporarily lock any of the modifier keys: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  <kbd>⊞</kbd>

**To temporarily lock <kbd>Shift</kbd>**

1. Turn Sticky Keys on by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> five times
2. With your mouse, select the first message
3. Press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and it will stay engaged until you select another key or click a mouse button.
4. select the last message in your block.

Modifier keys can also be locked without unlocking when you click your mouse.  This approach is achieved by double pressing them in quick succession.  This can be helpful if you are trying to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click a number of different items so that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key doesn't release after the next mouse click.

To unlock a locked modifier key, simply press it again.

[Windows Accessibility Options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-your-mouse-keyboard-and-other-input-devices-easier-to-use-10733da7-fa82-88be-0672-f123d4b3dcfe)

[Windows Sticky Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-stickykeys://)